# Dictionary Item Phrases are not indexed

Tags: lucene

In our solution (*Sitecore 8.2 rev. 170728*), the *Phrase* fields of dictionary items are not indexed. Since this is the easiest way for our content authors to find the correct dictionary items, this is quite annoying. This seems also to be the case in a Vanilla Siteore 8.2 Installation.

According to the Configuration, the field should be indexed (the *Key* field is indexed correctly), but it does not end up in the Index (checked with Luke).

Does anyone know why this field is not indexed and how I can make Sitecore index that field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior happens because ID of Phrase field is on excluded field list from indexing.

If you look into file : **\Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config** you will find inside section **exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField"** the phrase of field ID .

[image]

The Id of this Phrase field in Sitecore is the **{2BA3454A-9A9C-4CDF-A9F8-107FD484EB6E}**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I found it in the meantime. No idea how I could miss that :-)